# how to test if the console input equals the text with out and order

Tags: c#, while-loop, console, console-application

i know you can understand a lot of the title but what i mean is that i have this script that tests for the text in the console

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            if (Console.ReadLine() == "hello")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }
       }
    }
```

lets say i wanna add anther if statement like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            if (Console.ReadLine() == "hello")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "hello world")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
            }
       }
    }
```

the problem is that it test for the if statements in the order they are placed so how do i check for all of them at once for example if i write

```
hello world
```

it will give me the

```
messagebox.show("hello world")
```

anyway even tho its not the first if statement

i tried a while loop but it didn't seem to work

Comment: You could use `String.Contains("hello")`, but either way this is kinda off-topic

Comment: You could use `switch`.

Comment: @JimHewitt can you answer the post so you could go more into detail

Comment: @IDK  Look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853700/c-sharp-switch-case-string-starting-with

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should use [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) string method like

```
if (Console.ReadLine().Contains("hello"))
```

(OR) [`StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) method like

```
if (Console.ReadLine().StartsWith("hello"))
```

Per your comment, looks like you don't need to check any condition. BTW, not sure how/why you are using `MessageBox` class in a console application though.

Comment: but that wouldn't work become hello world contains the string hello too

Comment: they both start with hello tho

Comment: @IDKanything, isn't that's what you are asking actually? if not then edit your post and clarify

Comment: What about `if(String.Contains("hello") && String.Contains("hello world"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (myInput.IndexOf(mySubstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>= 0) then ...
```

for case-insensitive comparison